# Error while installation of Kubeflow on EKS

Tags: amazon-eks, istio, kubeflow

Here is run details (STDOUT) after running:

```
make deploy-kubeflow INSTALLATION_OPTION=helm DEPLOYMENT_OPTION=s3-only

https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/ingress/
Waiting for cert-manager pods to be ready ...
running command: kubectl wait --for=condition=ready pod -l 'app.kubernetes.io/instance in (cert-manager)' --timeout=240s -n cert-manager
pod/cert-manager-7c86cb795d-mk5hs condition met
pod/cert-manager-cainjector-7c96bbd9f5-qcxsz condition met
pod/cert-manager-webhook-f6648c54b-dqrkk condition met
All cert-manager pods are running!
==========Installing istio-1-14==========
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: [resource mapping not found for name: "global-deny-all" namespace: "istio-system" from "": no matches for kind "AuthorizationPolicy" in version "security.istio.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "istio-ingressgateway" namespace: "istio-system" from "": no matches for kind "AuthorizationPolicy" in version "security.istio.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "stats-filter-1.11" namespace: "istio-system" from "": no matches for kind "EnvoyFilter" in version "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "stats-filter-1.12" namespace: "istio-system" from "": no matches for kind "EnvoyFilter" in version "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "stats-filter-1.13" namespace: "istio-system" from "": no matches for kind "EnvoyFilter" in version "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "stats-filter-1.14" namespace: "istio-system" from "": no matches for kind "EnvoyFilter" in version "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "stats-filter-1.15" namespace: "istio-system" from "": no matches for kind "EnvoyFilter" in version "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "tcp-stats-filter-1.11" namespace: "istio-system" from "": no matches for kind "EnvoyFilter" in version "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "tcp-stats-filter-1.12" namespace: "istio-system" from "": no matches for kind "EnvoyFilter" in version "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "tcp-stats-filter-1.13" namespace: "istio-system" from "": no matches for kind "EnvoyFilter" in version "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "tcp-stats-filter-1.14" namespace: "istio-system" from "": no matches for kind "EnvoyFilter" in version "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "tcp-stats-filter-1.15" namespace: "istio-system" from "": no matches for kind "EnvoyFilter" in version "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "x-forwarded-host" namespace: "istio-system" from "": no matches for kind "EnvoyFilter" in version "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "istio-ingressgateway" namespace: "istio-system" from "": no matches for kind "Gateway" in version "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
ensure CRDs are installed first]
```

I have followed the docs as provided.

```
https://awslabs.github.io/kubeflow-manifests/docs/deployment/prerequisites/#docker
https://awslabs.github.io/kubeflow-manifests/docs/deployment/rds-s3/guide/
```

$ kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.22.6-eks-7d68063